# Plot Points on Graph using C#

Tags: c#, graph

I have points of the form (x,y) and I need to plot these points on a graph(line graph).The graph needs to be continuous and not discrete.This I need to do in C# using some API for graphs and not by graphics library.Please suggest how to do and If possible please share the code as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use standard `Chart` control from Windows Forms, then this code:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[0].Title = "N";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].Title = "FIB(N)";
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series[0].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "Fibonacci numbers";
Tuple<int,int> t = Tuple.Create(0,1);

for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
  chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, t.Item1));
  t = Tuple.Create(t.Item2, t.Item1 + t.Item2);
}
```

This will draw Fibonacci Sequence continuous XY graph.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use WPF then check out [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/). They even have a demo of a continuous graph that re-scales as it goes along.